# MySQL check for columns that are not empty

Tags: mysql, database

How do I check, if a column is not empty, meaning that it is neither NULL, nor is it blank. In some languages there are expressions that combine both, is there something like that in MySQL?

In other words, is there a way to simplify this query?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE Name != '' AND Name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong re "is there a way to simplify this query?". `SELECT * FROM \`table\` WHERE Name != ''` works. WHERE keeps rows for which its condition is true. If name is null then the inequality is null & the row is dropped. But you might *actually* want an expression that can ony be true or false. Eg for certain use in a larger expression or as the condition of a CHECK, which is satisfied by true or null. The problem is that your question is not clear about the "meaning" of "check" given that SQL has non-boolean conditions, with three truth values, true/false/null.

Comment: The condition in the WHERE is how we express what you want, that Name is neither NULL nor the empty string. ("Empty" is a poor choice to describe what you want, and "blank" is a poor choice to describe the empty string.) However, re your example query, it happens that if it would be appropriate as *the topmost condition in a WHERE* (and in certain other special contexts) then one can instead drop the "AND ..." and get the same query result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is the only way that you can perform this search. I would recommend setting a default of `NULL` or an empty string so that you know what to expect. Once you have the default set you could update all empty values to that default.

---

As stated by @philipxy in comments:

> The accepted answer is wrong re "is there a way to simplify this query?". `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name != ''` works. `WHERE` keeps rows for which its condition is true. If name is null then the inequality is null & the row is dropped.

I didn't think this was right, but after testing I see that you are right! +1

```
select * from users;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
|  2 |      |
|  3 | NULL |
+----+------+

select * from users where name != ''
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
+----+------+
```

Taking this into account, I still suggest that you set a default value of `NULL`.

Comment: Well, I suppose it's not *the only way*, but perhaps no other method is any more efficient.

Comment: @philipxy I feel my answer addresses "In some languages there are expressions that combine both, is there something like that in MySQL?". I interpret this as NULL and empty strings meaning the same thing in OPs case.

Comment: @Jim Wright: Exactly. Think of the function `empty` in PHP, for instance, that returns true if you pass an empty string, 0, NULL, false, 0 as a string etc.
It's just out of convenience to keep code short in some cases, I know that technically such a function doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Smokey_Bud & JimWright Neither of you seems to have understood my comments, that the question & answer (& now your comments) are worded too sloppily to know what the output of the desired expression is supposed to be for what input. Eg the question wrongly says of two different meanings that one is the other "in other words". Eg the answer wrongly states "this is the only way that you can perform this search" (since the 2nd conjunct is unnecessary there). I'm sure the answer helped the asker, but the posts & comments are all unclear about what is being asked & answered.

Comment: @philipxy Just tested this and I was surprised to see that you're correct! I'm updating the answer.

Comment: I would agree that the conjunction is the better choice, expressing the intent regardless of context. (And at no runtime cost for any reasonable optimizer.) Clarity... yeah....